# Bug on the moderator election page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

> ### **Disclaimer:** The following screenshots are *examples* and may *not reflect my voting decision* (I purposefully played around with the votes to test the bug).

See the screenshots below coming from the [election page](https://math.stackexchange.com/election).

[image]
[image]

and this happens regardless of the candidate. The bug disappear when being on close to the top of the page:

[image]

I hard refreshed the page several times but the problem does not disappear.
The bug seems particular to chrome as I can't reproduce it with safari.
I have a mac.

Comment: I would put the disclaimer with a ## and blockquote just to make sure that everyone sees it.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Is that you meant?

Comment: Yeah. That is what I meant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've gotten this fixed and the fix should be deployed some time today (current revision is 2017.10.13.27422, so anything after this should be fixed).

Thanks for reporting!